# Hardcoded ui-sref works, renedered ui-sref doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

This works:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="app.project.edit({projectId: 1})">Back</button>
```

This doesn't (nothing happens after clicking):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="{{backstate.state}}">Back</button>
```

When I view the source code of the rendered webpage in both cases I get:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="app.project.edit({projectId: 1})" type="button">Back</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Maybe this will help:

`AppControler.js`:

```
angular.module("app").controller("AppController", function($scope, $state, $rootScope, SessionService, NavigationService) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.goBack = function () {
        $state.go(NavigationService.getBackstate().state);
     };
});
```

`NavigationService.js`:

```
angular.module("app").service("NavigationService", function() {
    "use strict";

    var that = this;

    this.backstate = {
            state : "default state"
    };

    return {
        getBackstate : function() {
            return that.backstate;
        },
        setBackstate : function(backstate) {
            that.backstate.state = backstate.state;
        }
    };
});
```

`ScenarioListController.js`:

```
angular.module("app").controller("ScenarioListController", function($scope, $modal, $state, ngTableParams, NavigationService, project, scenarios) {
    "use strict";

    // [...]
    NavigationService.setBackstate({ state : "app.project.edit({projectId: " + project.id + "})"});
    // [...]
});
```

Comment: Hi @pmichna, have you changed your markup {{ }} to ({ }).

Comment: @chandu What do you mean? `ui-sref="({backstate.state})"` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a binding problem.

If the directive ui-sref is binded to the string `{{backstate.state}}` before it has been converted to its actual value, it would try to resolve the state `{{backstate.state}}` and not

```
app.project.edit({projectId: 1})
```

You could try with :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="goBack()">Back</button>

function myController($scope, $state) {
   $scope.goBack = function () {
      $state.go($scope.backstate.state);
   }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help - still nothing happens after the click. If I change `$state.go($scope.backstate.state);` to `alert('test');`, the popup appears, so the function `goBack()` is called properly.

Comment: Did you try to listen to `$state` events to log errors ? Try the `$stateNotFound` event. More details here : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#$stateNotFound